# Como inserto url's dentro de email en cakephp 3?

Tags: php, email, cakephp

Quiero enviar un email por medio de la clase `Cake\Mailer\Email;` y al insertar un link `<a href="url"></a>` me inserta otra url que incluye el host del transporte configurado en el `bootstrap.php`

**Mi accion en el controller:**

```
$email = new Email();
        $email
            ->setTemplate('credito_generado')
            ->setEmailFormat('html')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setCc(EMAIL_SALIENTE)
            ->setSubject('Credito generado')
            ->setViewVars([
                'c_nombre' => $nombre,
                'c_paterno' => $apellido_paterno,
                'c_materno' => $apellido_materno,
                'c_plazo' => $plazo,
                'c_monto' => number_format($total, DECIMALES),
                'c_id' => $id
            ]);
        $result_email = $email->send();
        $this->log('RESULT_EMAIL: '.print_r($result_email, true), LogLevel::DEBUG);
```

En **src\Template\Email\html\vista.ctp** unicamente imprimo las variables y un enlace con:

```
<a href="<?= \Cake\Routing\Router::fullBaseUrl().'/nexumclub/creditos/tabla-pdf/'.$c_id ?>">VER</a>
```

Comment: Hola @SergioHernandez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías publicar el código que intentaste hasta ahora? Es mucho más sencillo responder, y encontrarás más chances de que alguien se interese si ya hay una base sobre la cual enfocarse en algo concreto. Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano soy nuevo en esto, espero me pueda explicar.